# JSX Tag Red highlight

Tags: reactjs, jsx

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncGOK.png)
I used create-react-app to create a project. Usually, everything works fine, but today I don't know why the < > characters are showing up in red warnings. I use VSCode as my code editor and have some extensions like Eslint and Prettier installed.

I tried disabling Eslint, but it didn't work. I don't know how to fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should share some code screenshots for clarification of error.
Following solutions might help your problem :

1. maybe you are declaring or defining something wrong in App.Jsx file.
2. use rafce for initial syntax of JSX file. Do download all useful extensions for VSCODE :
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets